# Python order of operations involving "in" and "=="

Tags: python

I noticed the following strange behavior:

```
'a' in 'a' == True # Returns False
('a' in 'a') == True # Returns True
'a' in ('a' == True) # throws TypeError
```

How is the first expression parsed? Both placements of parentheses yield different results.
(Python 3.6)

Comment: The relevant phrase is "chained comparison"; there are lots of Q/A pairs already on the site, but it's hard to know what phrase to google first.

Comment: @BradSolomon: the first _does_ return True.  But it's a chained comparison, so `'a' in 'a' == True` is exactly the same as `('a' in 'a') and ('a' == True)`, which is `True and False`, which is False.  This is covered in the relevant section of the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature as described in the [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) section.

`in` and `==` are membership and comparison operators respectively.

From Comparisons:

> ... expressions like `a < b < c` have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:
>
> [...]
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

Comment: Why `'a' in 'a' == True` is false?

Comment: @RafaelC: Because `'a' == True` is false.

Comment: @RafaelC Because you can't evaluate a String to a Boolean

Comment: If it only has to do with operator precedence, shouldn't two of the three statements (either 1 and 2 or 1 and 3)  evaluate to the same answer?

Comment: @RafaelC: It's no different than `a < b < c` except that it uses different operators.

Comment: Nice, so what happens is `('a' in 'a') and ('a' == True)`